# mysql loading csv file plus additional columns into a table

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile, import-csv

I am reading articles and thread on how to load a csv file into a table, but I also need to add additional columns.  Is this possible?

Below is my table:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lid       | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| uDate     | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cID       | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| active    | int(1)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| user_ID   | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

above are additional columns I need to pass in, below are all the columns in the CSV file

```
| fName     | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lName     | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lAddress1 | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lAddress2 | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lCity     | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lState    | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lZip      | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lPhone    | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lEmail    | varchar(96) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field1    | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field2    | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| field3    | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| regCode   | varchar(32) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And to load the file:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/myfile.csv' INTO TABLE myTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(fName,lName,lAddress1,lAddress2,lCity,lState,lZip,field1,field2,field3,regCode) ;
```

## UPDATE

How can I also pass in `lid,uDate,cID,active,user_ID` ?

These fields are:

```
lid = listID 
cID = customerID 
active = defaults to inactive, but entrycan be later activated  
user_ID = initially null, but later updated with a properly assigned userID.
```

In my php script, they are already collected as `$lid,$cID,0,$userID`

Comment: Where do the values of these other columns come from?

Comment: Are they already in the table, and you want to update those rows with the values from the CSV? Does the CSV include the unique ID of the row so we can know which row to update?

Comment: @barmar - i update last question to better clarify what the other columns are and where they are coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `SET` clause to set additional columns other than the ones in the CSV.

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/myfile.csv' INTO TABLE myTable
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    (fName,lName,lAddress1,lAddress2,lCity,lState,lZip,field1,field2,field3,regCode)
    SET lid = ?, cID = ?, active = 0, user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("iis", $lid, $cID, $userID);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I did some more indepth reading on `LOAD DATA`.  I can use it for more than just my initial OP.  One of which is `REPALCE`.  Using that, is there a way to do a conditional for `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $file REPLACE INTO TABLE myTable ...`  to test if `active=1` to not update it or if `user_ID != NULL` to not update it?

Comment: You would have to change all the column names in the column list to `@fName, @lName, ...` format. Then everything gets set in the `SET` clause: `SET fName = IF(active = 0 AND user_id IS NULL, @fName, fName), SET lName = IF(active = 0 AND user_id IS NULL, @lName, lName), ...`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say....update everything in the row but the `active` and `userID` columns IF those columns have specific values.  update row regardless, but only update `active` and `userID` columns if conditions are met for each of those columns.  if `active=1`, don't update it.  if `userID != null` don't update it.

Comment: That's even easier. `SET lid = ?, cID = ?, active = IF(active = 1, active, 0), userID = IF(userID IS NULL, ?, userID)`